# Flutter: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin'

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

I have been trying to run my Flutter code on IOS device. However I am getting some errors regarding non-modular headers inside Framework module.

**Logs:**

```
While building module 'firebase_core' imported from
/Users/admin/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fi
rebase_auth-0.20.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:5:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from
/Users/admin/Desktop/Ali/GuestInMe/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/firebase_core/firebase_core-umbrella.h:13:
In file included from
/Users/admin/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fi
rebase_core-0.7.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:11:
/Users/admin/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fi
rebase_core-0.7.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePlugin.h:9:9: error:
include of non-modular header inside framework module
'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin':
'/Users/admin/Desktop/Ali/GuestInMe/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase
Core/FirebaseCore.h'
[-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
/Users/admin/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fi
rebase_auth-0.20.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:5:9: fatal
error: could not build module 'firebase_core'
#import <firebase_core/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

**What I have tried:**

1. I tried to change build settings of Xcode and allow non-modular imports -> flutter clean -> pod install in ios folder -> flutter run
2. Tried changing the file to public from project, but it already was public.
3. Reinstall all the pod files.

   'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin':
   [image: Screenshot]

Comment: I just had a nearly identical issue with the Facebook ShareKit SDK (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1649)

I wish I could give a solution, but I ended up creating a new flutter project (with Swift iOS project) and re-writing all my native code in Swift. I do not know if the solution was Swift vs Objective C, or a new Flutter project vs older (my project was 2 years old)

I would suggest creating a new flutter project, including those dependencies, and building. If you get the same issues, open an issue with the Flutter team. If not, it is a config issue somewhere :-(

Comment: Creating a new flutter project solved this issue for me as well. I just replaced the newly created ios folder into my old project though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What worked eventually:

1. Put all the `pubspec.yaml` dependencies to the latest version.
2. Delete `pubspec.lock`, `Pods` folder in `ios` and `Podfile.lock`
3. Run `flutter clean` -> `flutter pub get` -> `cd ios` -> `pod install` -> `cd ..` -> `flutter run`

And you should be good to go

Answer (score 5):

You can fix it by editing Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
    configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
  end
end
```

Comment: The most  Helpful  answer, It actually work!